# How to open a link of node in custom region?

Tags: 7, navigation

I create a custom region in sub-theme. I have constructed a map, on which there is a markers when you click on a link (Image 1) description opens on a full page (as on Image 2). How to open a description in the custom region? (example of custom region is on Image 1) Also I need to transition link eg *http://localhost/node/32* to open map (front page) and opens the description in the custom region?
Someone had to deal with such a task? How this functionality can be implemented?

Image-1

> [image: Image 1]

Image-2

> [image: Image 2]

Comment: Do you mean rendering a node with ajax?

Comment: Yes I do not want to overload the page with the map, I want to load content of node in custom region (right side) by click on it link. I've already implemented with module [Form block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock)  inputing content of node in custom region (when you press the blue button). You can see it on [site](http://forestry.in.ua)  But I can not figure out how to load content of exist nodes in custom region.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your block programmatically as explained in this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/easy-way-to-create-blocks-programmatically), and then in the block_view function, add the content of your node as the block's content, for example:

```
$imported_node = node_load($imported_nid);
$block['title'] = $imported_node->title;
$block['content'] = $imported_node->body;
```

You will have to tweak the values to fit your node content, structure you want to output